# Process activemq jms message with multiple mule instances is not effective

Tags: jms, cluster-computing, activemq-classic, mule

I came across an issue of multiple mule instances with activemq. our setup is like we have a mule instance in a front end server and we have several backend/application servers (lets say A, B,C, D) for faster processing the request with mule instances installed in it. The communication between frontend and backend is through activemq JMS messaging. Once the message is posted on the queue, any of the backend server (activemq listener) picks up the message and the application makes use of the message. My scenario is when the backend server A gets the message, application processes the message suddenly the application (daemon) goes down. My expectation is any other backend servers (say B. C, D) should take the request and continue process it. I have tried with maxRedelivery attribute also, the message is getting redelivered as expected but again same backend server A picks the message instead of other active application servers and end up in failure since application (daemon) is stopped running in server A.

Note: I have used JMS-transaction.

Does anyone have any idea about how to delegate the the work to other application server (mule instances) when a processing server end up in failure?

Comment: Is ActiveMQ embedded in Mule or running as a standalone instance?

Comment: It would also be interesting to see how you've configured the ActiveMQ connection factory: what redelivery policy, DLQ, etc...

Comment: Activemq is a installed in separate instance. Mule is going to connect with activemq.(<jms:connector name="myConnector" ... this is how i am connecting to JMS)

Comment: With the information you provide the only answer I can give you is: it should work fine.

Comment: Do you have any idea of server A should stop listening when it ends with exception so that others servers will pick it up after redelivery by server A?

Comment: If you consume in transactions and have properly configured the redelivery policy, this should all happen automatically.